# Client Credentials Grant in Google oAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-openid

I am trying to authenticate the communication between two backend services using [google oAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) server. It looks like Google does not support [Client Credential Grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749), rather it provides [Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service).

Is there a way I can achieve client credentials grant using Google Auth Server? Can I use Service Accounts to communicate between services outside Google Cloud?

Comment: Googles auth grants you access to Googles data.  Im not sure why you would want to use it to communicate between two of your own services.  For that you should be using your own auth server and creating client credentials on that.   No google does not support client credentials grant

Comment: Thank you. Our services already use the Google auth server for authenticating the users (Authorization Grant flows).  Therefore, I would like to explore the possibility of using the same server to use server-to-server communications. Definitely will go to a separate auth server if there is no possibility.